# Can we use assert to find if overflow happens while assigning value to C variables?

Tags: c, debugging

I recently came to know that `assert` in C can be used for debugging.

I wrote the below C snippet to ensure that input is not zero.

example code --

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
int main(){
    int a;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    assert(a != 0);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to ask whether we can use `assert` in C to check variable assignment overflows also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
long a = X;
int  b = a + 40;
assert((long)b == a + 40);
```

Comment: it asserts that the computation/assignment of the larger type has the same result as the narrowed type

Answer (score 2):

In order to avoid undefined behaviour, you'd want the `assert`ion to occur before the integer overflow.

Perreal's code is a step in the right direction, but it's not perfect because it invokes undefined behaviour by overflowing the integer before the assertion.

Here's the example I'd use:

```
long a = X;

assert(a < LONG_MAX - 40); /* Assert that a is less than LONG_MAX - 40, which
                            * proves that we can add 40 without invoking
                            * undefined behaviour.
                            */


assert(a + 40 >= INT_MIN);
assert(a + 40 <= INT_MAX); /* Assert that once 40 is added, the result will fit
                            * into an int without invoking implementation defined
                            * behaviour.
                            */

int  b = a + 40;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to use `assert()` for input validation.  There are two reasons for that:

1. Your code will probably fail if the assertions are not enforced because it is compiled with `-DNDEBUG` or equivalent.
2. The error handling behaviour is not usually acceptable for end users; the crash is counter-productive as far as they are concerned.

You should handle input errors through other mechanisms.  For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a;
    if (scanf("%d", &a) != 1)
        ...report I/O problem...
    else if (a == 0)
        ...report invalid input...
    else
        ...use known-to-be-non-zero value...
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the `scanf()` family of functions does not handle integer overflow gracefully.  If you are concerned about that, consider reading the data using a function such as `fgets()` and then using `strtol()` or one of its relatives to convert the string; these functions do handle and report overflow.

With (signed) integer overflow calculations, you could use `assert()` to ensure the value won't overflow (it is far too late to assert after the overflow has occurred; you've invoked undefined behaviour and anything could happen).  However, you should consider whether the error reporting behaviour of `assert()` is acceptable.